# How to get value of textbox in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I just started using React.js, and I'm just not sure whether there is a special way to get the value of a textbox, returned in a component like this:

```
var LoginUsername = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
  },
  handleChange: function (evt) {
    this.setState({ value: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100) });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As described in [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) You need to use **controlled input**. To make an input - **controlled** you need to specify two props on it

1. **`onChange`** - function that would set component `state` to an input `value` every time input is changed
2. **`value`** - input value from the component `state` (`this.state.value` in example)

Example:

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: 'Hello!'};
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
```

More specifically about textarea - [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-textarea-value)

Comment: So how would I use the above to get the current value of the textbox?

Comment: By replacing `input` element on `textarea`

Comment: @DmitriyNevzorov how should I achieve the same thing on the functional component.

Answer (score 7):

just update your input to the value

```
var LoginUsername = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
     return {
        textVal:''
     }
 },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.textVal} autofocus="autofocus" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
  },
  handleChange: function (evt) {
    this.setState({ textVal: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100) });
  }
});
```

Your text input value is always in the state and you can get the same by this.state.textVal

Comment: Could you please provide a use case scenario for the above?

Comment: If you want to prefill the textinput from the server , then you need to a field in the state

Comment: I'm trying to access the value from outside `LoginUsername` - right now I'm trying to use `LoginUsername.state.textVal`, but it isn't working for me...

Comment: then u can use ref