# Get text from textbox react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to get the input out of a textbox using ReactJS but am not sure how

```
import React from 'react'

class component extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
          super()
          this.state = {
          word: String('')

   }
  }

 increment() {
     this.setState({
     word: this.state.word += ''
 })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>The message is: { this.state.word } </p>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.word} onChange={(event) =>this.handleChange(event.target.value)} />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Word" onClick={() => this.increment()} />
            {/*<p><input type="button" value="clear msg" onClick={() => this.eraseWord()} /></p>*/}
        </div>

  )
 }
}
```

The text from the textbox should be added onto the message is:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of textbox in React?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420396/how-to-get-value-of-textbox-in-react)

Comment: Ok I am not sure where to put the  handleChange: function (evt) {
    this.setState({ textVal: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100) });

Comment: After the `render(){ ... }`.

Comment: You should then delete the question and create more specific one. By the way, your current question is incomplete, it ends with a colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two `state` variables, one will store the current value of `textfield`, and another one will store the complete value, and inside `increment` method append the `textfield` value to complete value and set it to '' again, Try this:

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            word: '',
            new: '',
        };
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState({
            word: this.state.word + this.state.new,
            new: '',
        })
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({
            new: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>The message is: { this.state.word } </p>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.new} onChange={(e) =>this.handleChange(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Word" onClick={() => this.increment()} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Check the `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hse607rr/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `handleChange` method:

```
class component extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            word: ''
        };
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState({
            word: this.state.word + ''
        })
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({
            word: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>The message is: { this.state.word } </p>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.word} onChange={(event) =>this.handleChange(event.target.value)} />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Word" onClick={() => this.increment()} />
                {/*<p><input type="button" value="clear msg" onClick={() => this.eraseWord()} /></p>*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That works so far I want the message to only update when the user clicks the add word button. It should store what was in the box at the time of the button click and allow the user to add onto what was previously entered

Comment: Ah, in that case in `handleChange` store the value to a different state property then append that to `word` in `increment`